# Python permissions issues with Ransomware Protection turned on

Tags: python, file, windows-10, runtime-error

After changing the Ransomware Protection on windows (GroupPolicy), python has been causing all sorts of weird errors for me.  I am not getting filenotfound errors when trying to write to a directory that exists.  My snippet is as follows:

```
import os
print("Does Dir Exist: ",end="")
print(os.path.isdir(test_dir))
print("Test Reading....")
with open(os.path.join(test_dir,"test_read_file.txt"),'r') as outrf:
    print(outrf.readlines())
print("Test Writing....")
with open(os.path.join(test_dir,"test_file.txt"),'w') as outwf:
    outwf.write("Test Writing to file")
print("Done!")
```

When I do this, I get the following output:

```
Does Dir Exist: True
Test Reading....
['test reading']
Test Writing....
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-fec57d58c3b2> in <module>
      6     print(outrf.readlines())
      7 print("Test Writing....")
----> 8 with open(os.path.join(test_dir,"test_file.txt"),'wb') as outwf:
      9     outwf.write("Test Writing s;dfhas;dhfadf")
      10 print("Done!")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:...
```

This works fine without the Ransomware Protection turned on.  Is there a way around it?

Comment: Are you allowed to write to that directory/file?

Comment: yes I can easily edit create and move (outside of the python env)

Comment: I figured out that it was the ransomware protection that was turned out by GroupPolicy... now is there a specific way around it for my dev....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify where the file comes from... Try to put the whole path or add "" before your path "test_file.txt"